# Is it possible to program the Vertex VX-2200 using the back DB 15-pin connector?

Tags: equipment-operation, radio-programming

The service schematic of the Vertex Standard VX-2200 VHF radio shows that the `ACC5` and `ACC6` pins of the back DB 15-pin connector are connected to pins `EXT_TXD` and `EXT_RXD` pins on the main processor.

Can those pins (or some other pins in the same connector) be used to program the radio or do I *have to* use the RJ45 connector in the front?

Comment: Hi Ronan, I think this is off-topic for ham.SE, since VX-2200 is definitely not a Ham device, but a trunking controller for people with a commercial license; see [the manufacturer's website](http://www.vertexstandard.com/lmr/trunking/vx-2200): *for flexible mobile business communications in the VHF or UHF Land mobile radio bands*, so you might want to explain in which context you're using the device (you can probably use it as a ham mobile device, but you're not saying)

Comment: @MarcusMüller I am actually trying to use it as a ham fixed station in the 2m band for now. The radio isn't used exclusively for trunking nor for commercial licenses, since it works from 134 to 174MHz. See [the non-trunking page](http://www.vertexstandard.com/lmr/Mobiles/VX-2100-2200). Also, I'm not in the US, so regulation is a bit different, if still very similar.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to find the answer in their service manual. http://www.repeater-builder.com/yvs/pdfs/yaesu-vx-2100-2200v-service-manual.pdf

Comment: The service manual doesn't give a specific answer, although it mentions a "programming cable".

Comment: Correct, it mentions a 15pin cable and it appears to be what was being described.

Comment: Usually something like this that requires a special programming cable also requires special software from the manufacturer. It isn't an open specification.